# How to find the element that matches the condition in Python?

Tags: python

I have 4 elements a,b,c,d and I do not know the values of a,b,c,d. But I know the values that a,b,c,d can have are in the range (1,4). To be more specific a can be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. Same applied for b,c,d.

I want to check which one of these (a,b,c,d) has the value 1 and display that element.

For example, if c=1 I want c to be displayed.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Are the elements unique in value? What if b and c were both 1?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're willing to help you, but we are not clairvoyant. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54956785/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: This is what I have:
a_tag = 1
b_tag = 2
c_tag = 3
d_tag = 4
Tag values are unique.
The tag that has the value 1 becomes the name tag.
To do this the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you look at the dictionary

```
   d={'a':2,'b':3,'c':1,'d':1}
```

how about:

```
   for k in d.keys():
      if d[k]==1:
         print(k)
```

that should print 'c' and 'd'

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be testing each variable:

```
a = 3
b = 4
c = 2
d = 1

x = 1
if a == x:
    print('a')
elif b == x:
    print('b')
elif c == x:
    print('c')
elif d == x:
    print('d')
```

This can be done as long as the number of variables is reasonably small. If this is a thing you need to do often, I'd suggest using a different data structure instead (e.g. a `dict`):

```
my_dict = {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}
x = 1
matching_elements = [k for k in my_dict if my_dict[k] == x]
print(matching_elements[0])
```

If multiple variables (or, in the `dict` case, keys) have the same value the first method will print the first occurrence, while the second might or might not return the first one depending on heaven's alignment due to `dict`s not being ordered (it will return only one though).
If you want to print all variables having that value you can do it replacing all `elif` with `if` or, in the second case, `print(matching_elements)`.

The hacky way (that **will** come back and bite you) is something on the line of this:

```
itervar = None  # If this does not exist the following will crash
for itervar in locals():
    if locals()[itervar] == x:
        print(itervar)
```

and this will print all variables having the same value as x.

Comment: a = 1
b = 3
c = 2
d = 4

#my_dict = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d}
my_dict = [a, b, c, d]
x = 1
matching_elements = [k for k in my_dict if my_dict[k] == x]
print(matching_elements) ---- why do you think this is not working?

Comment: Assuming I interpreted your code correctly you are creating a `list` containing the **values** of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`: `[1, 3, 2, 4]`. You are then asking Python to print the value `k` in the list such that the `k`th position of the list contains a value equal to `x`.

Comment: The interpreter then does the following:

`matching_elements = []`
`k = 1`
`if my_dict[k] == 1:  # nope, my_dict[1] is b and b is 3`
`# also my_dict is a list`
`    matching_elements.append(k)  # not executed`
`k = 3`
`...`
`# nothing actually matches, but it would not be what you are trying to get anyway`
`k = 4`
`if my_dict[4]... # !!! my_dict[4] does not exist!`
and the script crashes complaining of `list index out of range`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/). More specifically, the pandas [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html)

```
import pandas as pd

numbers = {'a':2,'b':4,'c':1,'d':3}

numseries = pd.Series(numbers)

boolseries = numseries == 1

print(list(numseries.index[boolseries]))
```

Output: ['c']

Might be a bit overkill for such a small amount of data, but extremely useful should you find yourself needing to do this with larger data sets. It also handles the case where there is more than one element that meets the condition.